# Python Gui (Tkinter) procces

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, thread-safety

This is my code:
http://pastebin.com/eN6xZ40P

I got two errors that I cannot understand:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python26\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:/Users/user-pc/Desktop/mail/someTK.py", line 32, in sendMail
    msg = MIMEText(output['Body'])
KeyError: 'Body'
```

Comment: 1. Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **in the question**. 2. *That's only one error!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to operate your interface correctly.

The various email fields are populated in the `fetch()` function which is called when the `<Return>` key is pressed, not when the `Send` button is clicked. If you fill in the form fields, then press `<Return>`, and then click `Send` it will try to send the email.

I don't know if it's the *best* way, but it can be made to work by adding the same binding as for `<Return>` to the `Send` button:

```
    b1 = Button(root, text='Send', command=sendMail)
    b1.bind("<Button-1>", (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e)))
```

An alternative would be to call `fetch()` within `sendMail()`, before constructing the email message.

An even better UI improvement would be to disable the `Send` button until all required fields have been supplied, but this is outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: thanks for your help ,
Should I delete the bind line?
What should i need to do?

Comment: Actually, I was wrong about the SMTP instantiation - `smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587)` is acceptable. I've edited the answer appropriately.

Comment: @pythonMan: updated answer with suggested fix.

Comment: @pythonMan: you're welcome. When you get a chance, you can accept the answer and upvote if you like.